# How to hide chart legend in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot2 object and I would like to hide the legend name. I'm using `col` in `ggplot` to define different colors and when I put in `labs` `col = ""` to hide it, it creates two legends.

My code:

```
dados_wide %>% 
  filter(variavel %in% c("mm30d","mm7d")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = data, y = value, col = variavel, size = variavel)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date("2020-03-20"), xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date()), 
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = +Inf), fill="#ffe6e6", alpha = 0.07, color = NA) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 100) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%Y") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#B0ADAD','#454545')) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(0.4, 0.8)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", col = "", title = "Consumo de Energia Elétrica - Consumidores Livres",
       subtitle = "Base 100 = Média Primeira Semana de Fev/2020") +
  facet_wrap( ~ atividade, scales = "free_y", nrow = 4) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray85", size = 0.3),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(linetype = "blank"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "gray45", size = 0.3, linetype = "solid"),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

Chart without `col = ""` in `labs`
[image]

Chart with `col = ""` in `labs`:
[image]

How do I remove the "variable" and leave only the "mm30d" and "mm7d"?

Comment: Try adding `+theme(legend.title = element_blank())` and let me know if worked.

Comment: You can also use `name=NULL` in whichever `scale_*`.

Comment: Thanks @Duck, it worked!

Comment: @AlexandreSanches Great, I have added it as complete solution. Please check and if you think it was helpful you could accept the answer or upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete solution would be:

```
dados_wide %>% 
  filter(variavel %in% c("mm30d","mm7d")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = data, y = value, col = variavel, size = variavel)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.Date("2020-03-20"), xmax = as.Date(Sys.Date()), 
                ymin = -Inf, ymax = +Inf), fill="#ffe6e6", alpha = 0.07, color = NA) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 100) +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b-%Y") +
  scale_color_manual(values=c('#B0ADAD','#454545')) +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(0.4, 0.8)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", col = "", title = "Consumo de Energia Elétrica - Consumidores Livres",
       subtitle = "Base 100 = Média Primeira Semana de Fev/2020") +
  facet_wrap( ~ atividade, scales = "free_y", nrow = 4) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray85", size = 0.3),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(linetype = "blank"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "gray45", size = 0.3, linetype = "solid"),
        legend.position = "bottom",legend.title = element_blank())
```